# iPhone: can you tell me the difference b/t (NSObject *)obj&(NSObject *obj)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers

Can you tell me what the difference is between 
`-(NSObject *)obj` and `-(NSObject *obj)`?

Comment: Please make up your mind what you're asking, your question title and body are totally different.

Comment: i am so sorry mr.BoltClock, i mean both r same

Comment: So do you want us to compare `(NSObject *obj)` and `(NSObject *obj)`, or `-(NSObject *)obj` and `-(NSObject *obj)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(type)obj tells the code that you have an object "obj" and it is of type "type"

(type *)obj tells the code that you have a pointer to an object "obj" and it is of type "type"

Examples:

(int)n means I'm giving you an integer called n
(float)n means I'm giving you a float called n

(NSObject *)obj means I'm giving you a pointer to an NSObject called obj

Non-Examples:

(int n) or (float n) or (NSObject *obj) are all nonsense

Answer (score 9):

`-(NSObject *)obj` is the signature of an instance method called `obj` that returns a pointer to an `NSObject`.

`-(NSObject *obj)` is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a cast (NSObject *)obj whilst the second is a (NSObject *obj) dispensable use of brackets